# How to rewrite Promise.All(promise1.then(), promise2) using RxJS in Angular

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs

I have this code:

```
this.account = await this.backend.getAccountInfo();
this.personInfo = await this.backend.getPersonInfo(account.userName);
this.config = await this.backend.getConfig();
this.loaded = true;
```

Now I want to get config in parallel with account and personInfo, so I have rewritten it using promises:

```
var p1 = this.backend.getAccountInfo()
    .then(account => this.account = account, handleError("account"));

var p2 = p1.then(account => this.backend.getPersonInfo(account.userName))
    .then(personInfo => this.personInfo = personInfo, handleError("current person");

var p3 = this.backend.getConfig()
    .then(config => this.config = config, handleError("config");

await Promise.All(p1, p2, p3);
initialized = true;
```

How do I rewrite it using RxJS, assuming backend uses HttpClient and returns Observable?

Comment: There is _nothing wrong_ in doing `.toPromise` and doing `Promise.all` on that.

Comment: I know but I would like to know the rxjs way, especially with error handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three requests, where the second on depends on the first one. The third one is independent, so you can do

```js
Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
  this.backend.getAccountInfo()
    .switchMap(account => this.backend.getPersonInfo(account.userName)
      .map(personInfo => [account, personInfo])
    ),
  this.backend.getConfig()
)
  .subscribe(([[account, personInfo], config]) => {
    this.account = account;
    this.personInfo = personInfo;
    this.config = config;

    this.loaded = true;
  });
```

But that's only *one* way to do it. For example, here's another way using side effects:

```js
Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
  this.backend.getAccountInfo()
    .do(account => this.account = account, () => handleError("account"))
    .switchMap(account => this.backend.getPersonInfo(account.userName))
    .do(personInfo => this.personInfo = personInfo, () => handleError("current person"))
  ),
  this.backend.getConfig()
    .do(config => this.config = config, () => handleError("config"))
)
  .subscribe(() => this.loaded = true);
```

You should be aware of how `forkJoin` deals with errors and add `catch` operators as you see fit. Also note that the second version will assign `this.account` even if the `personInfo` request then fails.

Comment: yeah, error handling is exactly what is not clear to me. How would you do error handling in the second example so that I can handle each error with custom message resp parameter? see my second code snippet

Comment: @Liero I've added the calls to the second example. Both `do` and `subscribe` take three arguments for emission, error and completion. So in the second argument to `do` you can call an error handler without stopping the error from propagating. You can also use `catch` to handle an error in a way that modifies the chain.

Comment: I'm trying to do if-else in swithMap. Basically I only want to get personInfo when account.isAuthenticate === true., otherwise personInfo may be set to some default value, e.g. null.  When I return empty<PersonInfo>() in switchMap, the final subscribe is never called, which makes sense. How do I handle it ideally?  should I return from<PersonInfo>([null])? it works but seems strange

Comment: Returning `Observable.of(null)` sounds fine to me. It also takes care of explicitly resetting `this.personInfo` in case it was already set before.